# calling akka.net actor hosted in c# executable through web api (c#)

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have an actor (akka.net C#) running in executable (or windows service).
I am trying to fetch data from that actor. If I try getting it from another exe (C#) it's working fine, if I try to call it from web api (C#) it's not working.

Is it possible to call actor hosted in exe (C# akka.net) using rest end point (in different process)?

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake I was doing, when I was calling the akka method from web api , I was passing string in Ask method instead of proper Message class.

My bad, apologies.

Regards,
Amit